# Opening a File Pathway in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, solidworks

I am having trouble with winform opening a drawing. The error I am getting says NullReferenceException was unhandled and is highlighting the pathway. any help is appreciated. Thanks

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Open Solidworks Drawing
        ModelDoc2 swModel = default(ModelDoc2);
        DocumentSpecification swDocSpecification = default(DocumentSpecification);
        string sName = null;
        long longstatus = 0;
        long longwarnings = 0;
        // Drawing document path and name         
        swDocSpecification = (DocumentSpecification)swApp.GetOpenDocSpec("C:\\location\\????.slddrw");//File Location
        sName = swDocSpecification.FileName;
        // Sheet name         
        swDocSpecification.SheetName = "BOM"; //Open to the BOM sheet
        swDocSpecification.DocumentType = (int)swDocumentTypes_e.swDocDRAWING;
        swDocSpecification.ReadOnly = true;
        swDocSpecification.Silent = false;
        // Open the specified sheet in the specified drawing document         
        swModel = swApp.OpenDoc7(swDocSpecification);
        longstatus = swDocSpecification.Error;
        longwarnings = swDocSpecification.Warning;
    }
```

Comment: using SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks;

Comment: what is the pathway? why do you have a "file path" (or simply path) like this: C:\\location\\????.slddrw !?

Comment: I mainly want to know if I am referencing the pathway correctly

Comment: ("R:\\Engineer\\Russell Saari\\CONFIGURATOR MODELS\\PBC Detailed Linear Actuators\\MLD028D\\MLD028DMLD028D-xPMx.SLDDRW")

Comment: Because it is a super long pathway

Comment: I think its safe to assume that path is meant by pathway

Comment: I am new to programming in general I appologize

Comment: Is swApp a valid object reference?

Comment: yeah its referenced earlier public SldWorks swApp; I should have posted that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possibilities as to why you're getting the NullReferenceException

1. swApp is null and calling anything inlcuding `GetOpenDocSpec` won't work
2. Something inside GetOpenDocSpec isn't written the way it supposed to,  and its not doing the correct checking. And so its throwing a null exception

It should pretty easy to just check if swApp == null using your debugger. Using the autos or watch windows, hovering over the variable, ?swApp == null from the command window, etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe c:\\");
```

this can help